# Creating an object dynamically where the class name is given as a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an object of a class dynamically by sending the class name as a string. I have searched in all the java forums but i couldn't get the answer which i wanted. 
Here is my requirement,
i have a class with name Agent,

```
package somePack;

public class Agent{
  private String Id;
  Private String Name;
  public String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

package somePack;

public class Employee{
  private String Id;
  Private String Name;
  public String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
public class create{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      newCreate("Employee");
      newCreate("Agent");
   }
   public static void newCreate(String name){
      String path="somePack."+name;
      Class cls=Class.forName(path);
      System.out.println("Class Name " + cls.getName());
  }
}
```

Now my question is, cls.getName() gives me the class name, but now i want to create the object for that class i.e., for Employee class and Agent class respectively, but how can i create the object for them? The string that is passed may be something else from the other method, how can i create an object for such kind of things.

Can anyone help me....

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Class.forName() Lookup for this.

Answer (score 9):

> but now i want to create the object for that class

Then use the [`Class.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method if you never need to handle constructors with arguments, or use [`Class.getConstructor(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) or [`Class.getConstructors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29) otherwise. (Call [`Constructor.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) to invoke the constructor.)

Comment: hi Jon , I want to create an object for a class of the string variable's value. If i don't know it as "Agent", it might be something else, then how can i generate it dynamically... i hope you got my question...

Answer (score 7):

Use [Class#newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)

```
Object o = Class.forName(path).newInstance();
```

You can then cast this to Agent.

```
Agent agent = (Agent) Class.forName(path).newInstance();
```

Comment: If i use Object o = Class.forName(path).newInstance(); then how can i set and get the values for the class.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for your reply, but if there are some 50 of classes and based on some criteria i send the related string as the parameter, then how can i know which class object to be created dynamically. I.e., now i'm passing it as "Agent", next if i may pass "Employee" then how this method will be helpful for me to generate the string variable's value as an object

Answer (score 5):

On the grounds that the class has a default constructor (ie no parameters), you can simply call [`Class#newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29).

If it has parameters, it becomes a little more complicated.

You'd have to get a reference to the appropriate `Constructor` via [`Class#getConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29), passing in the expected parameter class types.

Once you have that, you can call [`Constructor#newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) passing it the appropriate objects